# Delphi XE - faster alternative to System.Pos function

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe3

I know that a lot of code from FastStrings has been included into Delphi XE. I need to process several thousands of files and do some text processing. Is there a 'faster' alternative to the [System.Pos](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos) routine?

Comment: RBA: depending what u search for.
You can search for character, for substring or for an any of array of substrings.
Those would give you different algorithms.

It also may depend upon whether u need a position or to check that symbol (or a set of symbols) is present/missed in string.

Plain char search is just linear scanning.
Substring search should skip parts of string after unsuccesfull match and thus a speedup gained (i don't remember names this optimization is attributed to, but it is rather obvious idea)

Comment: Basically if you really have speed-critical way you'd better look at larger picture and think if Pos function is matchign your needs or you're misusing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. [`PosEx` function is from FastCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCode#Contributions_to_Delphi_RTL) and is much faster compared to System.Pos. It is located in [StrUtils](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils) unit.

Comment: If PosEx is much faster that System.Pos, how do you explain this implementation: `Result := System.Pos(SubStr, S, Offset);`

Comment: @UweRaabe - so they downgraded it, or changed `System.Pos` and made `PosEx` a wrapper? I don't have XE2 to check myself.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera, actually it is in XE3 (you really get confused when you have more than one IDE open). In XE3 the System.Pos is from FastCode (at least for 32-bit).